# can't run python3 on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu

I can't run python3 on ubuntu 14.04

```
alias python=python3
python --version
```

outputs:

```
Python 2.7.6
```

and

```
python3 --version
```

gives same output

As I understand python3 should be preinstalled on the system?

I tried to run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

But there is an error:

```
  Setting up idle-python3.4 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3) ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/compileall.py", line 120
    print('*** ', end='')
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing package idle-python3.4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 idle-python3.4
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you require Python3 to be preinstalled rather than installing it via your package manager?

Comment: i have tried to run 

    sudo apt-get install python3
but there is an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if `python3` is installed:

```
python3 --version
```

Add `alias python=python3` into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file.

You must logout then login again.

I recommend using `python3` for python 3.x. There are a lot of programs depending on python 2.x so better not to remove it. However you can uninstall it: `sudo apt-get remove python2.7`

Before uninstalling Python 2.7 read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315015/how-can-i-remove-python-2-7-after-installing-python-3-3).

Comment: After that do `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_aliases` to activate your alias without logout or restart.

Comment: And if you do use `python3` for version 3 of Python there is little / nothing you need to do as you _already have it_ as my answers illustrates.

Comment: I believe it could help me if I did everythinh "right" way. But I made some mistakes while installing virtual env and virtual env wrapper. So I crashed a lot of stuff and some dependencies, And  I couldn't figure out what exactly was wrong and how to work it out. Then I just completely reinstalled everything

Comment: And now I also believe that the best way is to run python 3 is just type python3 instead of aliases or overwriting system files

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand how aliases work. You need to reset the hash table via `hash -r` (see `man bash` for details).

Also:

```
edd@max:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.1+
edd@max:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
edd@max:~$
```

and

```
edd@max:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Dec  9  2015 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Dec  9  2015 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2629712 Aug 11  2011 /usr/bin/python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3546104 Jul  2 14:05 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Jul  2 14:05 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Dec  9  2015 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 23 06:00 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 Oct 19  2012 /usr/bin/python3.2 -> python3.2mu
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2863832 Oct 19  2012 /usr/bin/python3.2mu
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4439120 Mar 31 06:51 /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4439120 Mar 31 06:51 /usr/bin/python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Mar 23 06:00 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Dec  9  2015 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      58 Mar 25 17:01 /usr/bin/pythontex -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     306 Mar 25 17:01 /usr/bin/pythontex3
edd@max:~$
```

You want to look into `dpkg-alternatives` to switch the default from `python2` to `python3`.  I'd be careful though as some system scripts may expect `python` to be version 2.

Comment: It is `man bash` as I wrote, then search for the `hash`  _function_  in bash  (ie `/ RET hash`).